# WSO2 ESB having issues when I use multiple callout mediator calls with in a single sequence

Tags: wso2-esb

I was trying to write a proxy service that has multiple calls involved where output from first service is used to create request to second service and eventually output from second service will be transformed before even i make the third one. Right now I am having issues at the second step itself.

Here is a proxy configuration that I have where output from service 1 is being used to create the payload for second service call.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="CreateListingFromGetLocation" statistics="disable"
    trace="disable" transports="http https">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property action="set" name="userName" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="Rama"/>
            <property action="set" name="password" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="Ramapass"/>
            <property action="set" name="clientIP" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="1.11.111.111"/>
            <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <tem:Pool_GetNewSession>
                                <tem:Name>$1</tem:Name>
                                <tem:Password>$2</tem:Password>
                                <tem:ClientIP>$3</tem:ClientIP>
                            </tem:Pool_GetNewSession>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg expression="get-property('userName')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('password')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('clientIP')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log category="INFO" level="custom" separator=",">
                <property expression="//*" name="Triggering getSession API call.."/>
            </log>
            <callout action="urn:Pool_GetNewSession" serviceURL="http://localhost:8989/GetNewSession/">
                <source type="envelope"/>
                <target xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xpath="//Pool_GetNewSessionResponse"/>
            </callout>
            <property action="set"
                expression="//tem:Pool_GetNewSessionResult"
                name="sessionId" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"/>
            <log category="INFO" level="custom" separator=",">
                <property expression="get-property('sessionId')" name="SessionID"/>
            </log>
            <property action="set" name="siteId" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="51"/>
            <property action="set" name="productId" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="8351"/>
            <property action="set" name="perfDateList" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="12/13/2014 E"/>
            <property action="set" name="marketingCode" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="Premium"/>
            <property action="set" name="targetSystem" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="Govinda"/>

            <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest>
                                <tem:Name>$1</tem:Name>
                                <tem:SiteID>$2</tem:SiteID>
                                <tem:sXMLInput>
                                <request>
                                 <displaydata>
                                 <fetch_display_data>
                                 <fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name>
                                 <param type="operator">$1</param> 
                                 <param type="string">$2</param>
                                 <param type="string">$3</param>
                                 <param type="string">$4</param>
                                 <param type="string">$5</param>
                                  </fetch_display_data>
                                 </displaydata>
                              </request>
                              </tem:sXMLInput>
                                <tem:TargetSystem>$6</tem:TargetSystem>
                                <tem:Session>$7</tem:Session>
                            </tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg expression="get-property('userName')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('siteId')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('productId')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('perfDateList')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('marketingCode')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('targetSystem')"/>
                    <arg expression="get-property('sessionId')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>

            <log category="INFO" level="custom" separator=",">
                <property expression="//*" name="Triggering getLocation API call.."/>
            </log>
            <callout action="urn:Pool_SendXMLRequest" serviceURL="http://localhost:8989/GetLocation/">
                <source type="envelope"/>
                <target xpath="//result"/>
            </callout>
            <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=","/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

I have observed two things, the log mediator that was dumping the payload before even i make the second service call was showing the payload three times - not sure if I am missing something. Here is how the payload gets duplicated..

```
2014-04-18 09:32:27,961 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-20]  INFO CreateListingFromGetLocation Triggering getSession API call.. = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><soapenv:Body><tem:Pool_GetNewSession><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:Password>Ramapass</tem:Password><tem:ClientIP>1.11.111.111</tem:ClientIP></tem:Pool_GetNewSession></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><tem:Pool_GetNewSession xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:Password>Ramapass</tem:Password><tem:ClientIP>1.11.111.111</tem:ClientIP></tem:Pool_GetNewSession></soapenv:Body><tem:Pool_GetNewSession xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:Password>Ramapass</tem:Password><tem:ClientIP>1.11.111.111</tem:ClientIP></tem:Pool_GetNewSession>RamaRamapass1.11.111.111
2014-04-18 09:32:27,972 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-20]  INFO CreateListingFromGetLocation SessionID = vf103lotgawlfltjjuldtamv|51
2014-04-18 09:32:27,980 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-20]  INFO CreateListingFromGetLocation Triggering getLocation API call.. = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><soapenv:Body><tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:SiteID>51</tem:SiteID><tem:sXMLInput><request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><displaydata><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata></request></tem:sXMLInput><tem:TargetSystem>Govinda</tem:TargetSystem><tem:Session>vf103lotgawlfltjjuldtamv|51</tem:Session></tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:SiteID>51</tem:SiteID><tem:sXMLInput><request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><displaydata><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata></request></tem:sXMLInput><tem:TargetSystem>Govinda</tem:TargetSystem><tem:Session>vf103lotgawlfltjjuldtamv|51</tem:Session></tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest></soapenv:Body><tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><tem:Name>Rama</tem:Name><tem:SiteID>51</tem:SiteID><tem:sXMLInput><request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><displaydata><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata></request></tem:sXMLInput><tem:TargetSystem>Govinda</tem:TargetSystem><tem:Session>vf103lotgawlfltjjuldtamv|51</tem:Session></tem:Pool_SendXMLRequest>Rama51<tem:sXMLInput xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><displaydata><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata></request></tem:sXMLInput><request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><displaydata><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata></request><displaydata xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><fetch_display_data><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data></displaydata><fetch_display_data xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><fn_name>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mkt</fn_name><param type="operator">Rama</param><param type="string">51</param><param type="string">8351</param><param type="string">12/13/2014 E</param><param type="string">Premium</param></fetch_display_data>eapi_fetch_mkt_locations_mktRama51835112/13/2014 EPremiumGovindavf103lotgawlfltjjuldtamv|51
```

I might be doing something wrong when I construct the request payload for second service call..

Can someone help?

Comment: Looks like its a logging issue but the data is going fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a logging issue but the data is going fine.